# PoolingDataSource - How to use a driver-specific PreparedStatement implementation

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I've implemented the [commons dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) `PoolingDataSource` and its working perfectly - right up until I ran into an issue of using a specific implementation of the `java.sql.PreparedStatement` interface.

```
((OraclePreparedStatement) getStatement()).registerReturnParameter(index, sqlType); 

java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement 
cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatemen
```

I understand why this is happening.  **Is there any way to use a vendor-specific implementation of PreparedStatement but still be able to use the connection pooling that is provided by Commons DBCP?**  I'd like to use the registerReturnParameter() and getReturnResultSet() which are specific to Oracle's implementation.  I know I've violated cardinal rule #1 ...

Also, the PoolingDataSource is wrapping a OracleXADataSource which makes me believe that it's somehow possible to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of `DelegatingPreparedStatement` implies that it simply delegates to the original statement. So you call `delecatingPrepartedStatement.getDelegate()` which will return the `OraclePreparedStatement`.

But really, try not to do this.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for breaking the rules on this one :/